# loop through JSON array to generate Multiple Countdown timer?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Currently I'm using a jquery count down timer plugin [(This Plugin)](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) to generate the Counter through Ajax call .
for now its working fine with no problem for a single call but when i tried to generate a multiple counter whole looping through Json array it doesn't work . 
JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'time.php', 
                        async: false, 
                        dataType: 'json', 
                        success: function(data) { 
                            var response = data ;
                            $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                                var time = new Date(item.time) ;
                                $('.timer').append('<li id='+ i +'></li>');
                                 $('#'+i).countdown({
                                 until: time, 
                                 compact: true,
                                 format: 'HMS'
                             });  
                            });
                        }, 
                        error: function(http, message, exc) { 
                            time = new Date(); 
                    }
                }
            ); 


            })
```

PHP

```
<?php
  $now = time() + 9999; 
  $now1 = time()+ 5000; 
  $data = array($now,$now1);
  $json = array();
  foreach ($data as $value){
      $json[] = array(
          'time' => $value
      );
  }
  echo json_encode($json);
 ?>
```

this is the Json output

```
[{"time":1365712506},{"time":1365707507}]
```

When I tried to show up the result of loop without setting the time it works fine and showing the right result .
But after setting the time and setting the count down timer its shows 00 instead of the counter

```
    00:00:00
    00:00:00
```

Comment: Which countdown plugin?

Comment: I am guessing the dates are not in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to multiply the dates with 1000

```
var time = new Date(item.time*1000);
```

I also changed the class to ID and added a letter to the iDs of the LIs for non-html5 browsers

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/XrF7c/)

```
$(function(){ 
  var response = [{"time":1365712506},{"time":1365707507}];
  $.each(response, function(i, item) {
    var time = new Date(item.time*1000) ;
    $('#timer').append('<li id="t'+ i +'"></li>');
    $('#t'+i).countdown({
      until: time, 
      compact: true,
      format: 'HMS'
    });  
  });
});
```

Comment: i forgot to print the time format through the php i printed it as int

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your dates, I dont believe that they are in the furture.

```
console.log(time);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65ysV/)

Comment: That was exactly my comment, Bryce!

Comment: @mplungjan I must have been making that example when you commented.  Sorry about that.